# Did ignored tags feature change

Tags: bug

For politics I like to have questions about united-states grey, not because they are uninteresting, but just because I like to spot questions about the rest of the world.

But the last few days my questions are all regular, even if I remove the ignore tag and add it again.

Does anyone know if something changed.

Comment: In my experience, the "ignore tags" feature has always worked by just hiding the posts entirely. So instead of questions tagged with "united-states" appearing in grey, you just won't see them.

Comment: I am able to reproduce that bug, but not only on politics stack exchange but on various other stack exchange sites as well, including our flagship stackoverflow. So it does not seem to be a problem specific to Politics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I’m closing this question because there is already a question on the general stack exchange meta about this problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken

Comment: Good news, this is now [tag:status-completed]!